# Rendered texture mapping is different than in the viewport

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I have UVmapped an object to a texture/image but when viewing it in the render it changes, this does not apply too all however I can't quite figure it out.

[image: Example 1 showing UV in edit material mode]

[image: Example 2 via render]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are working on a different UV map from the one you've set to actually render.

Under Properties Editor > Object Data > UV Maps, you can click on the camera icon next to a UV map name to activate it for rendering :]

[image]

Comment: Where it shows me two options, is this for each individual object are those two examples for two objects or just one? I'm sure I will find out soon but just for clarification.

Comment: Here, the two uv maps are for the same object. You can create as many uv maps as you like, but use only one at render time, which you can specify with the camera icon. In the 3d view, if the viewport shading is set to anything other than Rendered, you will see the result of the selected uv map (highlighted in blue), whereas once you switch to Rendered shading, it will switch to the map specified for rendering.

Comment: Situations like yours tend to occur when you join (ctrl+j) two objects with separate uv maps. If you want to merge the two uv maps when joining, you have to give the maps a common name. Otherwise, you will end up with two different uv maps as shown above.